# a type of Key Error recommendation occurs in the content-based recommendation system?

Tags: python, machine-learning, syntax-error, keyerror

I'm building a content-based recommendation system model but when I want to get a recommendation, I find an error with the type of key error that I don't understand because I'm still a newbie in machine learning, can anyone help me solve the error in my code?

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-f89afa6121c5> in <module>
----> 1 jobs_recommendations(jobs_recomend.Kemampuan['Golang, Backend Development, SQL Server, MySQL'])

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    386                 except ValueError as err:
    387                     raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 388             raise KeyError(key)
    389         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    390 
# 
# KeyError: 'Golang, Backend Development, SQL Server, MySQL'
```

in the content-based recommendation system model , I've made TfidfVectorizer , cosine similarity and others before making recommendations but the error still persists

**randomize datasets**

```
jobs_recomend = jobs_new
jobs_recomend.sample(5)
```

TfidfVectorizer

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# Inisialisasi TfidfVectorizer
tf = TfidfVectorizer()

# Performs idf calculations on capability data
tf.fit(jobs_recomend['skill'])

# Mapping array from integer index feature to name feature
tf.get_feature_names()
```

Matriks tfidf

```
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(jobs_recomend['skill'])
tfidf_matrix.shape
```

Dataframe matriks tfidf

```
pd.DataFrame(
    tfidf_matrix.todense(), 
    columns=tf.get_feature_names(),
    index=jobs_recomend.skill
).sample(22, axis=1).sample(10, axis=0)
```

cosine similarity

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
 
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix) 
cosine_sim
```

```
# Create a dataframe from the cosine_sim variable with rows and columns of abilities
```

```
cosine_sim_df = pd.DataFrame(cosine_sim, index=jobs_recomend['skill'], columns=jobs_recomend['type of work'])
print('Shape:', cosine_sim_df.shape)
 
# Melihat similarity matrix pada setiap kemampuan
cosine_sim_df.sample(10, axis=1).sample(20, axis=0)
```

get Recomendation

```
def jobs_recommendations(skill, similarity_data=cosine_sim_df, items=jobs_recomend[['skill','type of work']], k=10):
       
    index = similarity_data.loc[skill].to_numpy().argpartition(
        range(similarity_data))
   
    closest = similarity_data.columns[index[-1:-(k+2):-1]]
   
    closest = closest.drop(skill, errors='ignore')
    return pd.DataFrame(closest).merge(items).head(k)

jobs_recommendations(jobs_recomend.skill['Golang, Backend Development, SQL Server, MySQL'])
```

**
ERRORR **

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-f89afa6121c5> in <module>
----> 1 jobs_recommendations(jobs_recomend.Kemampuan['Golang, Backend Development, SQL Server, MySQL'])

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    386                 except ValueError as err:
    387                     raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 388             raise KeyError(key)
    389         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    390 

KeyError: 'Golang, Backend Development, SQL Server, MySQL'
```

Comment: I think you have a typo. `tf.fit(jobs_recomend['skill'])`  should be `tf.fit(jobs_recommend['skill'])`

Comment: hallo, it looks like the error isn't there because when I checked, the variable that holds the dataset uses the jobs_recomend variable